# Relate to another table without using prefixes

Tags: php, cakephp

So i have a task of creating a mobile version of an existing website but its built with a different framework which i didnt started.

The client wants to use CakePhp on it. so im using CakePhp 2.5.7.  My question is.  Is there a way to relate another table from an existing table without using prefixes?

To make it more clear i have this on my controller

```
public function index(){
    $this->loadModel('Bulletin');
    $bulletins = $this->Bulletin->find('all');
}
```

in my model

```
class Bulletin extends AppModel{

    var $useTable = 'bulletin';

    var $hasMany = array(
        'BulletinComment' => array(
            'className'   => 'BulletinComment',
            'foreignKey'  => 'bulletinid',
        ),
    );
}
```

but the `bulletincomment` table on the database has no prefix.  and showing error on page

```
Error: Table bulletincomments for model bulletincomment was not found in datasource default.
```

I tried creating `BulletinComment` model like this

```
class BulletinComment extends AppModel{

    var $useTable = 'bulletincomment';  

}
```

but to no avail.  Im still getting error.  Is it possible to use any relation without adding prefixes?

Comment: clear the cache after creating the model

Answer (score 0):

Assuming prefixes are setup in the database connection (`/app/Config/database.php`) you can override it for one table if you add this to the model:

```
public $tablePrefix = '';
```

Or you could remove the prefix in the connection and add it back for the models that need it, depending on which is faster.